# Repeated keystroke "w" for Agar.io

Tags: applescript

I've been searching for the relevant articles on the Internet and found nothing useful. Maybe I'm too stupid to understand.

I would like to create a script that automatically keep pressing the "W" key, like wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww, endlessly and as quick as possible when I press and hold the key, and it ends when I release the key.

"defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false" doesn't work in this case.

Thank you very much in advanced.

Comment: There is a way to do this with AppleScript. The only issue is that spamming keys like that can completely lock you out of your UI. One or two bugs in my various scripts in the past have forced me to force a shutdown from time to time... What, might I ask, is the purpose of this script? I may have a better way that doesn't require this.

Comment: @Froggard There's an online game called [agar.io](http://agar.io). One of the controls is pressing W. I think OP wants to endlessly repeat W's effect for as long as the key is held down.

Answer (score 1):

Karabiner:

```
  <item>
    <identifier>private.w2wRepeat</identifier>
    <name>Turn W key to W key repeat</name>
    <autogen>
      __KeyToKey__
      KeyCode::W,
      KeyCode::W,
      DelayUntilRepeat::RawValue::1,
      KeyRepeat::RawValue::1,
    </autogen>
  </item>
```

Comment: Thank you. I followed the official document and paste your code between the <root></root> to the original private.xml, reloaded the xml, checked the check box next to "Turn W key to W key repeat, , but I can't get it worked.